# Is there an API available for SharePoint 2010's JavaScript based Client Object Model?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2010

I've searched the farthest reaches of the internet, but I cannot find an online API for SharePoint 2010's JavaScript based Client Object Model.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming with online API you mean the MSDN documentation you can find it in this [MSDN article: ECMAScript Class Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee538253.aspx).

You should search Google for "Sharepoint 2010 ECMAscript" and you will find many useful articles explaining its use.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for! It's weird, but none of these pages ever showed up in the Google searches. Although, I wasn't including 'ECMAscript' in the keywords. Just JavaScript and SharePoint-2010.

Comment: Sometimes these searches can be a hassle with MS products... If you deem the question answered you can coose your desired answer with the checkmark on the left side.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post but I think this JS API could interest some other people : http://aymkdn.github.com/SharepointPlus/

It's a JS library to deal with Sharepoint 2007 and 2010